# Limitations of scipy.weave for more complex performance code

Tags: python, performance, scipy, f2py

1. Is there any **overhead of calling functions using *weave.inline()*** in
   comparison to direct call of native (C, Fortran) static compiled function? I was worrying that *weave.inline()* does compile the code every time the function is called (which it does not, fortunately ), but still I worry that it may slow down by doing some tests if the code is already compiled or not (I don't know how it works inside ).
2. Is it possible to **write also more complex (multifunction) C code using *weave.inline()***? I tried that and I got error `a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token`
3. Is there any possibility how to compile the code in such a way, that I can **call the functions independently**.

---

**Bacground / application / example**

I have a **N-Body** probem solver using **f2py** which consist of several functions ( one function evaluate forces between bodies, other functions integrate differential equations by RKF45 ).

Because I find it hard to make f2py work under Windows and I want make multiplatform python library, I'm trying to rewrite it to C and use *scipy.weave* based on this tutorial
http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformancePython

For illustration, I made example with much simpler differential equation dA(t)/dt = -k*A(t)

```
from scipy import weave
from scipy.weave import converters
from pylab import *
n = 100
As = zeros(n);
def testODE(A, k, n):
    code = r"for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { As(i)=A; A -= (double)k*(double)A; }"
    return weave.inline(code, ['A','k','n','As'], type_converters=converters.blitz, compiler = 'gcc')               
ks = arange(0.02,0.2,0.02)              
for k in ks:
    testODE( 10.0, k, n)
    plot ( As );
show();
```

This works just fine. I'm just not sure if there is some overhead due to weave.inline() calls.

However, If I make a separate function for evaluation of derivatives ( like the force in N-Body problem ) than I get error `a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token`

```
def testODE_multiFunc(A, k, n):
    code = r'''
        double evalDerivatives(double a, double b){ return a*b; }
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { As(i)=A; A -= evalDerivatives(k,A); }
        '''
    return weave.inline(code, ['A','k','n','As'], type_converters=converters.blitz, compiler = 'gcc', verbose=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an explanation of how compiled code is cached: [the weave catalog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html#the-catalog)

If you want to inline complex (multi-function) C code, you could define your functions in a separate header file (say, `foo.h`) and then pass that to the call to `inline`:

```
weave.inline(code, ['A','k','n','As'], headers=['"foo.h"'],
             type_converters=converters.blitz)
```

Note the strange quoting. From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.weave.inline.html):

> headers : [str], optional A list of strings specifying header files to
>   use when compiling the code. The list might look like
>   ["","'my_header'"]. Note that the header strings need to be in
>   a form than can be pasted at the end of a #include statement in the
>   C++ code.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about headers. One more question: When I use header files, how can I use numpy.ndarray inside the header file as global variable? I mean, now I adress it directly like _As(i)_ in header file I would rather need _As[i]_ or _double* As_. I have to convert the type somehow? Or do I need to copy the global _As(i)_ into some local _As[i]_, which will cost some performance?

EDIT: Ah, OK, it is probaly described here:
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Weave
sorry for stupid question

Comment: ah, OK, probably everything is described in examples in istalation folder of weave
Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\examples

Comment: One minor correction, the quoting should be reverse and extension .h is also required. like this `headers=['"nbody.h"']`